# Django way to "Pre-cache" an existing database table?

Tags: python, django, caching, psql

I have a 200MB sized csv file containing rows where a key term is matched against a list of strings inside the second column.

```
term_x | ["term_1","term_2"]
term_y | ["term_1","term_2"]
term_z | ["term_1","term_2"]
```

My Django app is not configured to use any complex memory caching (Redis, Memcached) and in practice, I want to pass a term into the database table to retrieve the corresponding list value. Due to its size however, retrieving the list from the correct row takes around half a second to do, on top of other actions being performed while loading the page.

Is it possible in Django to "pre-cache" this table upon server startup? i.e. add all of those values to the cache with the first column being the key? I have attempted something similar by overriding the "ready" method in my app.py to load the database table into the cache on startup, but I get null values when I try to use a term I know is in the table:

```
class MyAppConfig(AppConfig):

    name = 'test_display'

    def ready(self):
        print("Loading RS Lookup cache..."),

        #setup database connection....

        cache_df = pd.read_sql_query("Select * from table_to_cache", engine)

        print("Table loaded")

        for index, row in cache_df.iterrows():

             cache.set(row['term'], row['list_of_terms'], None)

        print("RS Table loaded")
```

My **init**.py in the same Django app has only one line:

```
default_app_config = 'test_display.apps.MyAppConfig'
```

Comment: Please provide the presumably not working code from `apps.py` (btw did you make sure you set the correct appconfig in the settings or in the `__init__.py`?)

Comment: Both of what you request has now been edited in.

Answer (score 1):

Check whether the following is correct:

1. In the project settings you did **not** configure caching or used the [local memory caching](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/cache/#local-memory-caching) as described in the documentation.
2. You only use the default cache (`from django.core.cache import cache`) or correctly handle cache names.
3. Make sure your code in `.ready()` actually stores the values you are trying to read later. You can use one of the following:

   ```
   assert "my_term" in cache, "The term is not cached!"
   ```

   or

   ```
   from django.core.cache.backends import locmem
   print(locmem._caches)
   # now check what you have inside using your very own eyes and patience
   ```

---

As for the following:

> Is it possible in Django to "pre-cache" ... ?

Your solution utilizes AppConfig.ready() which is generally a very good place for activities that your server should only perform once per instance. At least I am not aware of a better solution.